Passing credentials in ASPNET & OTP Authentication
There are 2 views

Index
VerifyAuthOTP

Both have the same controller , IndexController which implements Controller, that is IndexController : Controller
Expected flow: Landing on Index view and then enter userName and password (captcha as well), hit submit will take to another action  Index with params as login Model.
From here if user credential is valid then VerifyAuthOTP is called .
In VerifyAuthOTP, neither Session nor TempData remains if initialized in Index.
Therefore I tried to send it in query param using base 64 encoding but due to security concerns this has been rejected.
Is there any other way to do it ?

Do you use TempData in Index view? TempData is persisted for the next request unless it is read. So that let's say we define TempData in IndexController and display it in Index.cshtml, then we click the submit button, this is the second request and we already read TempData before, so we will get null value in VerifyAuthOTP action.

Used TempData  in Index , placed a value in it but when tried to access it  from VerfiyAuthOTP action it stated error implying not found the tempData and its count was 0 (zero)

Could you pls try to add TempData.Keep method like TempData["data"] = "this is the temp data"; TempData.Keep("data"); and see whether your issue still persist?

Added TempData.Keep("data"); but still the same issue

My temp data key is "data", yours might be something else... Could you pls try TempData.Keep(); and see whether it worked? If not, could you pls share a minimal sample for reproducing your issue so that I could test in my side?

neither Session nor TempData remains if initialized in Index

Just like you know, TempData is persisted for the next request unless it is read.

ASP.NET Core exposes the Razor Pages TempData or Controller TempData.
This property stores data until it's read in another request.

I had a test with codes below and it worked for me. I just add builder.Services.AddSession(); and app.UseSession(); in Program.cs so that I could use Session.
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["data"] = "this is the temp data";
        TempData.Keep("data");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionData", "session value");
        return View(new LoginModel());
    }

    public IActionResult login(LoginModel mod) {
        if (true) {
            VerifyAuthOTP();
        }
        return Ok("success");
    }

    public void VerifyAuthOTP() {
        var data = TempData["data"];
        var sessionData = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionData");
    }
}

public class LoginModel {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

I used a simple view
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.LoginModel

<div>@TempData["data"]</div>


<form asp-action="login">
    <div>
        <lable asp-for=@Model.UserName>user name</lable>
        <input asp-for=@Model.UserName />
    </div>
    <div>
        <lable asp-for=@Model.Password>password</lable>
        <input asp-for=@Model.Password />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>



Thanks a lot , added the useSession() , It Worked , but ended up  vanishing captcha in the box . lol
